# Highlight a part of a plot by drawing it in a different color

Tags: matlab, plot, highlight

Given a plot with e.g. a curve like shown on the following figure I want to highlight the curve in the interval 150 <= x <= 200. I would prefer simply drawing this interval in red instead of blue.

Is there a better way to do this than splitting my curve in 3 sets / 3 connecting curve parts? (3 intervals, first one for blue, sencond one for red, third one again for blue). Thanks for any hint![image: curve]

Comment: Just draw the highlighted part on top of the existing curve?

Comment: Thanks, that sounds good and simple! I somehow feel there won't be a better solution, but in case anyone knows a better one, let us know :-)

Answer (score 3):

A quick example:

```
%# plot data
x = linspace(0,2*pi,75);
y = sin(x);
plot(x, y, 'b.')

%# higlight points of interest
idx = (4 <= x & x <= 6);
hold on, plot(x(idx), y(idx), 'r.')
hold off
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do it would be to provide an n*3 matrix of color values, for n data points.

```
C = zeros(size(x,2), 3);
C(x>=150 & x<=200,1) = 1; % red
C(x<150 | x>200,3) = 1; % blue
scatter(x, y, 25, C, 'd', 'filled');
```