# Coloring specific points with specific colors on a graph in MATLAB plot

Tags: arrays, matlab, plot, figure

I have "classes", and "inputs" array. Both of arrays' dimensions are 1x2000.

In "classes" array, the clusters of data in "inputs" array are recorded. For instance,

```
classes = [5, 2, 4, 3, 5, ...]
inputs = [5.234, 6.345, 4.342, 2.532, 5.345, ...]
```

When I plot "inputs" array like `plot(inputs)`, I want to differently color each data which correspond to the specific clusters in "classes" array.

How can I manage this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to plot inputs vs. x. Please explain.

Comment: I want to plot inputs. And the cluster of each data in inputs array are recorded in classes array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to do something like:

```
x = 1:numel(inputs);
plot(x(classes == 1), inputs(classes == 1), '.b', 
     x(classes == 2), inputs(classes == 2), '.g', 
     x(classes == 3), inputs(classes == 3), '.r');
```

You can expand on this idea, such as looping over the classes, customizing color ordering, and more.
Please add more information to your question if you want a more specific or detailed answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Naveh, but right now the problem is, I cannot plot the graph continuously. Each cluster starts from x = 0. How can I manage to plot the graph continuously as original one?

Comment: You can use the classes array to directly colour the line, according to this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/11172348/1770618