# Highlight specific section of graph in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, highlight

I wish to highlight/mark some parts of a array via plot in MATLAB. After some research ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171384/highlight-a-part-of-a-plot-by-drawing-it-in-a-different-color)) I tried to hold the first plot, find the indexes for highlighting and then a new plot, only with those points. However, those points are being drawn but all shifted to the beginning of the axis:

[image: Status]

I'm currently trying using this code:

```
load consumer;   % the main array to plot (157628x10 double) - data on column 9
load errors;     % a array containing the error indexes (1x5590 double)

x = 1:size(consumer,1)';      % returns a (157628x1 double)
idx = (ismember(x,errors));   % returns a (157628x1 logical)

fig = plot(consumer(:,9));
hold on, plot(consumer(idx,9),'r.');
hold off
```

Another thing I would like to do was highlighting the whole section of the graph, like a "patch" on the same sections. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble is that you are only providing the y-axis data to the plot function. By default, this means all data is plotted on the `1:numel(y)` x locations of your plot, where `y` is your y-axis data.

You have 2 options...

1. Also provide x-axis data. You've already got the array `x` anyway!

   ```
   figure; hold on;
   plot(x, consumer(:,9));
   plot(x(idx), consumer(idx,9), 'r.');
   ```

   Aside: I'm slightly confused why you create `idx`. If `errors` is as you describe it (indexes of the array) then you should just be able to use `consumer(errors,9)`.
2. Make all data which you don't want to appear equal to `NaN`. Because of the way you're loading your error indices in, this is less quick and easy. Basically you'd copy `consumer(:,9)` into a new variable, and index all undesirable points to set them equal to `NaN`.

   This method has the benefit of breaking up discontinuous sections too.

   ```
   y = consumer(:,9);          % copy your y data before changes
   idx = ~ismember(x, errors); % get the indices you *don't* want to re-plot
   y(idx) = NaN;               % Set equal to NaN so they aren't plotted

   figure; hold on;
   plot(x, consumer(:,9));
   plot(x, y, 'r');            % Plot all points, NaNs wont show
   ```

Comment: Perfect. I was missing that. I actually tried adding the x-axis data, but was mixing things up (mixed `x(all)` with `consumder(idx)` -> dimensions error). Since I wasn't getting the issue, I guessed that I needed a logical variable, so I created `idx`. Now that all makes sense, that variable is useless. Thanks a lot!

Comment: One thing: since the sections to the drawn are separated from each other (e.g., 5:10, 20:25) if select a line (`'r'`) instead of points (`'r.'`), each of the sections are "connected" with a line instead of several line sections. Is there any easy way of separating the sections? Since the values are only vertical lines/spots, is there any tool to plot this instead of a connected graph? Thanks!

Comment: @Paulos I've updated suggestion 2. with an example. You should use this second method to break up discontinuous sections too.

Comment: Thanks for your time! I managed to work it out with `stem` as well.